# iOS Keyboard "Done" button load action

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch

I'm trying to get "Done" button on to load an action, preferably the action that I have for my button.

Here's the UITextField declaration

```
let someTextField = UITextField()
```

Trying to add a target to the textField

```
someTextField.addTarget(self, action: "loginActionButton", forControlEvents: .EditingDidEndOnExit)
```

Comment: What is your question? What is your exact problem?

Comment: He's trying to add functionality to the keyboards 'Done' button

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When the "Return Key" (or "Done") button is tapped, the delegate of your textfield will receive a set of callbacks including `textFieldShouldEndEditing:`, and `textFieldDidEndEditing:`. To respond to these, implement a `UITextFieldDelegate` and execute your action there, i.e. call `loginActionButton` in one of the delegate methods.

Relevant Documentation: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITextFieldDelegate/textFieldDidEndEditing: